# Filter heterogeneous list for type

Tags: scala, list, casting

I've an initial list that consists in different types of elements and I've to filter it to just take the int and double values.

For example `(1 :: "hello" :: 100 :: 3.14 :: ('a'::10::Nil) :: 'c' :: (5,7,'a') :: Nil)` should become `(1, 100, 3.14, List(10), (5,7))`

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution because once the list is passed to a method it becomes a List[Any] type of list and I need to know the type of each element before casting it. It wouldn't be a problem it didn't contain others substructures such as tuples as I could manage something with a pattern matching.

Is it possible somehow to get the specific type of a Any element and to cast it?

Comment: If you want to use a heterogeneous list, why aren't you using an `HList` from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is an exercise that was given by my professor so I can just use what is inside the scala documentation, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an academic exercise it's rather silly. You should be learning how to avoid situations like this instead of trying to deal with it. Still, bad code can be rather instructive at times.

```
def intOrDbl(la :List[Any]) :List[Any] = la.flatMap{
    case i:Int     => List(i)
    case d:Double  => List(d)
    case l:List[_] => List(intOrDbl(l))
    case t:Product => val res = intOrDbl(t.productIterator.toList)
                      res.length match {
                        case 0 => Nil
                        case 1 => List(res)
                        case 2 => List((res(0),res(1)))
                        case 3 => List((res(0),res(1),res(2)))
                        case 4 => List((res(0),res(1),res(2),res(3)))
                        // etc.
                      }
    case _ => Nil
}

val data = 1 :: "hello" :: 100 :: 3.14 :: ('a'::10::Nil) :: 'c' :: (5,7,'a') :: Nil
intOrDbl(data)
//res0: List[Any] = List(1, 100, 3.14, List(10), (5,7))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I dont know the length of my Product/Tuple? Is there a way to do a general purpose pattern matching for that case ?

Comment: @Jing, in the current Scala (2.12) tuples are limited to the maximum size of 22 so you can actually write an exhaustive `match`/`case` statement. In the future Scala (see [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/)) when tuples are modeled similar to shapeless [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples) there will be other means to write a generic code here.

Comment: I didn't know about the maximum size of tuples, this is helpful

Comment: @Jing, under naive implementation of tuples there must be some limit because the underlying type system of Java doesn't support anything matching Tuples of arbitrary size. So you have to have a separate class for each `TupleN` and you have to stop at some `N`. The particuar value 22 is of course a historical accident.

Answer (score 1):

One choice you have is to put your result type into an [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). Here is how it might work:

```
sealed trait IntOrDoubleOrList
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends IntOrDoubleOrList
case class DoubleValue(value: Double) extends IntOrDoubleOrList
case class ListValue(value: List[IntOrDoubleOrList]) extends IntOrDoubleOrList

def filterIntOrDouble(l: List[_]): List[IntOrDoubleOrList] = {
  l.collect({
    case iv: Int => IntValue(iv)
    case dv: Double => DoubleValue(dv)
    case lv: List[_] => ListValue(filterIntOrDouble(lv))
  })
}

def test(): Unit = {
  val origList = (1 :: "hello" :: 100 :: 3.14 :: ('a' :: 10 :: Nil) :: 'c' :: (5, 7, 'a') :: Nil)

  val f = filterIntOrDouble(origList)
  println(f)
}
```

Depending on you further needs you may extend the `IntOrDoubleOrList` trait with some helper methods like `foreach(intHandler: Int => Unit, doubleHandler: Double => Unit)`

Comment: I've tought something similar but it wouldn't help if an element is a tuple, would it? I don't really know how to handle an element if it is a tuple because I don't even know its lenght and the types it's composed of

Comment: @Jing, I think it would help if you defined your real high-level problem. It is hard for me to imagine a real world problem which really requires such stuff. There might be some easier ways to solve your real problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a real world problem, just an academic exercise that was given by my professor.